# Solution - Scale and center iframe proportional horizontally and vertcal

Tags: css, iframe, scale

I have a div on my index.php with an iframe containing all my other php-pages.
What I wanted was to scale the div horizontally and vertcal and still keep the content proportional in center.
It's easy with an img, but I could'nt figure it out with a div or an iframe.

I don't know if this has been solved in here before, and if so, I have'nt been able to find it, and I have struggled with it for a long time now.
Then suddenly I found a workable solution on:

https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/MajxzY?editors=110

So what I want with this post, is just to share it with others, who have the same problem.

```css
#master
{
position: absolute;
margin: 0% auto;
padding: 0 auto;
left: 0%;
top: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
background: #000000;
}


.slide
{
position: absolute;
padding: 0 auto;
left: 0%;
top: 0%;
left: calc(50vw - 89vh);
width: 177.7777777777vh;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background: #000000;
}


@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16 / 9)
{
 .slide
 {
 left: 0%;
 top: calc(50vh - 37.5vw);
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>


<div id="master">
 <div id="iframe_site" class='slide'>
  <iframe id="iframe_master" src="http://www.mrles.dk/test_2.php" name="iframe_master" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
```